# Session variable in class produces NullReferenceException

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, session, nullreferenceexception

I have a class with a subroutine as follows:

```
Public Sub SetPermissions()
    If IsNothing(HttpContext.Current.Session) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim session As HttpSessionState = HttpContext.Current.Session
        If Not IsNothing(session("UserId")) Then '<-- exception occurs here
            'Do Stuff
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I know that my session variable is not yet set, hence a null value, that's why i'm trying to handle it with `IsNothing`, but my code still bugs out on me.

Any ideas?
Cheers

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior in a test project. Is the `SetPermissions()` method getting called from an HttpModule that is running before `HttpContext.Current.Session` is initialized?

Comment: What line is the exception on?  Maybe HttpContext.Current is null and not HttpContext.Current.Session.

Comment: @SteveWellens: Sorry, the original post did indicate the line where the error occurred, I accidentally dropped it when I edited for formatting. It's back now.

Comment: I see..10 demerits anyways.  My original question/point is still valid.  Is session null at the point you access it?

Comment: setPermissions is being called in global.asax with by the following:  "Sub Application_AuthenticateRequest(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If Request.IsAuthenticated Then
            
            Dim _permissions As New Permissions.UserPermissions
            _permissions.SetPermissions()
             
        End If
    End Sub"

Comment: Though i thought if the session had not yet been created then first condition: "If IsNothing(HttpContext.Current.Session) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else" would have caught it

Comment: @rsbarro i think you  might have something. I tried simply 1 line: session("User") = "abc" and still go the same error. How do i intiate session when called from my global.asax

Comment: @LewisCallaghan: Take a look at my answer, I think you just need to move the code into a different event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to try to access `Session` variables from Global.asax, you need to make sure you use an event that is fired after `Session` has been initialized for the current request. If you take a look at the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx), you'll see there are several events you can wire up in the Global.asax (check out the list of events in the section "The request is processed by the HttpApplication pipeline").

If you wire up those events, you should find that `Session` is initialized before `Application_AcquireRequestState` is raised. If you move your code out of `Application_AuthenticateRequest` and into `Application_AcquireRequestState` then it should work properly.

Note that I used the following code to test when `Session` would be initialized (C#, sorry). I wired up each event in order from the documentation, and `Application_AcquireRequestState` was the first event where I saw `session == null` evaluate to `false`.

```
void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
    Response.Write("Application_AcquireRequestState: -> session is null: ");
    Response.Write(session == null);
    Response.Write("<br />");
}
```

Comment: Hey Mate Cheers, that seems to do the trick, I went for the following in my asax file:  Sub Application_PostAcquireRequestState( )
        If HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated Then 
            Dim _permissions As New Permissions.UserPermissionsBLL
            _permissions.SetPermissions(User.Identity.Name)
        End If
    End Sub